# Identity Role check works locally, but not on deployed instances - Entity Framework with Owin

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, owin, identity

I'm presented with this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found     or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.         (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)    
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web req    uest. Please review the stack trace     for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.    

SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's     App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provid    er     determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully che    ck for     existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:    

If the application is running on either Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008R2, special configuration steps are necessary to     enable automatic creation of the provider database. Additional information is available at: http://go.microsoft.    com/fwlink/?LinkId=160102. If the application's App_Data directory does not already exist, the web server accoun    t must have     read and write access to the application's directory. This is necessary because the web server account will auto    matically     create the App_Data directory if it does not already exist.    
If the application's App_Data directory already exists, the     web server account only requires read and write access to the     application's App_Data directory. This is necessary because     the web server account will attempt to verify that the Sql Ser    ver     Express database already exists within the application's Ap    p_Data directory. Revoking read access on the App_Data director    y     from the web server account will prevent the provider from     correctly determining if the Sql Server Express database alread    y     exists. This will cause an error when the provider attempts     to create a duplicate of an already existing database. Write     access is required because the web server account's credent    ials are used when creating the new database.    
Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.    
The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to     create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts.
```

This exception is thrown when I call this extension method on User:

```
public static bool IsInAnyRole(this IPrincipal principal, params string[] roles)
{
    return roles.Any(principal.IsInRole);
}
```

Thing is, this extension method works fine on my local machine. It's only on deployments (remote server and Azure - I've tried both) that this fails.

The exception seems to specify that it can't connect to SQL Express, but I shouldn't be using SQL Express at all. My only connection string points to a SQL Server.

I've tried a remote server's SQL database and an Azure SQL instance; the same exception is thrown.

I've also tried to ensure all relevant references are Copy Local = true.

I and my mates are completely stumped. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I believe I've tracked it down to the fact that Entity Framework is, at some point, creating and relying on a LocalDB instance, despite the fact that nowhere in my config or anywhere I can find such a configuration. Is there someplace this might be done automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! Figured it out.

The issue was specifically with Role Manager. This feature is enabled with the following web.config line:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

However - the above declaration, by itself, doesn't declare a connection string. One would think it'd default to whatever DefaultConnection string you have up at the top of the web.config, but that's not the case - it uses whatever's in machine.config. In my case, that was LocalDB/SQL Express.

To fix it, I did two things:

Installed Microsoft AspNet Providers, a NuGet package that gets all the various Identity providers (users, roles, etc) and equalizes their configuration.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers
```

Then, I ensured the roleManager node was fully declared:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

And now everything works!

Comment: I'd +1 this repeatedly if I could.. after spending hours on this problem, your solution worked for me. Thanks a million for posting your solution!